# equation of a plane that is perpendicular to a line segment.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the general equation of the plane which is perpendicular to the line segment between the points $A(1, 2, 9)$ and $B(3, 4, 12)$ that separates the line segment into $2$ equal parts. This is called the perpendicular bisector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vector $B-A$ is perpendicular to the plane. But $B-A=(2,2,3)$. So our plane has equation of the shape $2x+2y+3z=d$ for some constant $d$.

To find $d$, calculate the midpoint of the line segment $AB$. That midpoint must lie on our plane.

Answer (score 2):

If Mid Point Of A(1,2,9) and B(3,4,12) is $\vec a$ them $\vec a(2,3,\frac{21}{2})$

and normal to the palne is $ \vec n(3-1,4-2,12-9) = \vec n(2,2,3)$

Hence equation plane is given by

$\vec r.\vec n = \vec a.\vec n$

$(x,y,z).(2,2,3) = (2,3,\frac{21}{2}).(2,2,3)$

$2x+2y+3z = 4+6+\frac{63}{2}$

$2x+2y+3z = \frac{85}{2} $

$4x+4y+6z = 85$